# enforce same size for subplots with varying annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a figure with 3 subplots in one row. Only the left subplot has axis labels and tick labels on the y-axis, and only the right subplot has a color bar next to it. Thus, the width of the three subplots including annotations is not identical. Now I want to enforce the *size of the actual plot region* in the three subplots (imshow, say) to be the same. All I can manage for now is to have the size of the three subplots *including annotations* to be the same (which necessarily leads to different plot sizes) or to play with `a`, `b` ,`c` in

`gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3, width_ratios=[a, b, c])`

until I get satisfying results. Is there are way to find such `a`, `b` ,`c`automatically, or to otherwise *fix the plot size*?

Here is a minimal example where the third image is clearly smaller than the previous two:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

field = np.random.rand(800,800)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(18,6))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1,wspace=0.1)

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3)

ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])

plt.imshow(field)

plt.xlabel("$x$")
plt.ylabel("$y$")

ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])

plt.imshow(field)

plt.xlabel("$x$")
plt.ylabel("")

ax = plt.subplot(gs[2])

sc = ax.imshow(field, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)

plt.xlabel("$x$")
plt.ylabel("")

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="2%", pad=0.05)

cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, orientation = 'vertical', cax=cax)
cbar.set_label("colors")
cbar.set_ticks([0.0,1.0])

plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Can you include a complete minimal example?  My expectation is what you want should be the default behavior and what you are describing would be hard to do.